# Objective C Load PDF file in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, file, pdf, webview, nsdata

EDIT:
There was something wrong with my Base64 decoding. I searched for a external Base64 decoder and it working just like this:

This is the case:
I have a Base64 encoded byte array I get from a webservice and convert it to NSData:

```
NSData *data = [Base64 decodeBase64WithString:response];
```

And in my Webview Controller I declared:

```
[webview loadData:fileData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

fileData is the decoded data.

When I run this I get a gray screen.
So I assume I'm not giving it a correct `NSData` object.

Comment: You could try to write the data into a file `[data writeToFile:@"test.pdf" atomically:YES]` and then open that pdf with preview to check if you got a valid pdf file out of your base64 string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I already answered my own question when I was typing it.

> So I assume I'm not giving it a correct `NSData` object.

My Base64 decoding was wrong.

Using this statement works like a charm:

```
[webview loadData:fileData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

I'm just posting so other people can look at it of they have the same problem.

Comment: can you also explain the mistake done in your base64 decoding and how you fixed it so it would be useful.

Comment: can anyone give me above code version for WKWebView... After migration for UIWebView to WKWebView this stoped working,

Answer (score 2):

```
[webView loadata:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

That should do the trick for you, if it doesn't you can write it to a file as V1ru8 suggests, but that is an extra step in most of the cases.

Hope this will helps

Comment: As stated in my EDIT, my Base64 decoding was wrong. using textEncodingName:@"utf-8" works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already provided answers, I've found that loading `NSData*` into a `UIWebView` in the initializer function of a containing UIViewController doesn't work and there'll be no error.

The `NSData*`needs to be loaded into the `UIWebView` in the `viewDidLoad` function.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView is DEPRECATED, use WKWebView
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview?language=objc

Objective-C Example:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```

...

```
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screen);


WKWebView *wkwebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
//UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)]; //DEPRECATED

NSURL *targetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"fileName" withExtension:@"pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
//[webView loadRequest:request]; //DEPRECATED
[wkwebView loadRequest:request];

//[self.view addSubview:webView]; //DEPRECATED
[self.view addSubview:wkwebView];
```

Comment: Sidenote here: question was posted in 2011

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that:

```
UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:webview];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfFileName" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```